# How to set the value of radio button after submitting form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2. I have a search form that has radio buttons below it. It searches based on which of the radio buttons are selected. Currently I have this in my view:

```
  = radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free")
  = label_tag(:ad_type_free, "free")
  = radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "paid")
  = label_tag(:ad_type_paid, "paid")
  = radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "featured")
  = label_tag(:ad_type_featured, "featured")
```

So my question is this, how do I set the default radio button to be selected? I have tried using `radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free", :checked => true)`, but after submitting the form, it always selects that radio button. What I want is to select the value based on the previous request. Should I get the value from the url params? If so, how do I set the initial default value(when there are no previous searches)? Thanks a lot.

**Update**

I've created a helper method ad_type_selected?

```
  def ad_type_selected?(ad_type)
    selected_ad_type = params[:ad_type] || "free"
    (selected_ad_type == ad_type) ? true : false
  end
```

And I have this in my view:

```
  = radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free", :checked => ad_type_selected?("free"))
```

However, the radio button still doesn't get selected. Checking the logs, I see that the first call to the helper returns true, and the others false, which is what I want. But problem is it still doesn't select the radio button. If I check the input tag, I can only see that the checked attribute is set to "checked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, adding a checked attribute for all the radio buttons causes the last radio button to be always selected. So what I did is to just add a checked attribute if the params matched the radio button.

So for my example, I just used a helper to generate the appropriate radio button like so:

```
  def ad_type_radio_button(ad_type)
    selected_ad_type = params[:ad_type] || "free"

    if selected_ad_type == ad_type
      radio_button_tag(:ad_type, ad_type, :checked => true)
    else
      radio_button_tag(:ad_type, ad_type)
    end
  end
```

And have this in my view:

```
= ad_type_radio_button("free")
```

I know it's far from elegant, but it behaves correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm grave digging, but I just came across this.

```
<label class='checkbox-inline'>
  <%= radio_button_tag :option, :user, true %>
  Username
</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'>
  <%= radio_button_tag :option, :email, params[:option] == 'email' ? true : false %>
  Email
</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'>
  <%= radio_button_tag :option, :name, params[:option] == 'name' ? true : false %>
  Full Name
</label>
```

So... this will set the first button by default (and always), but if the other params are selected they'll become true. Radio buttons will always have the last `true` button selected for you, so as long as you put your default option first in the list, set to true, and the rest set to:

```
params[:name_of_your_buttons] == 'button_value' ? true : false
```

Comment: `params[:option] == 'name' ? true : false` is equivalent to `params[:option] == 'name'`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will set checked to false if params[:ad_type] is nil. Otherwise, it will set checked to true if params[:ad_type] is set to true.

```
radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free", :checked => (params[:ad_type] == nil ? false : params[:ad_type]))
```

Just in case you haven't seen the shorthand for if / then / else used above, it goes:

```
test-expression ? if_true_expression : if_false_expression
```

Comment: But params[:ad_type] contains a string, then should I use params[:ad_type] == "free" ? true : false ? And repeat this for all radio buttons?

Comment: That looks correct to me... play with it and see how it goes.

Comment: Or you can do something like params[:ad_type].present? which will return true if it is different of null or false

Comment: The radio button still doesn't get selected even when I add the checked attribute. I've updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag), `checked` isn't an options hash parameter, it is just a boolean.

This didn't worked (at least in rails 4):

```
= radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free", :checked => ad_type_selected?("free"))
```

It should be:

```
= radio_button_tag(:ad_type, "free", ad_type_selected?("free"))
```