# Ruby on Rails 3 - How Can I Check a radio_button_tag In My Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, radio-button

I have a radio button on a contact form where someone can select 1 of 5 values.  I do not have a default value for the radio button.  I am using form_tag since this data will not be stored on a database.

Here is my code for the radio button:

```
    <%= label_tag "Purpose:" %>&nbsp;
    <%= radio_button_tag :purpose, '1' %><%= label_tag :purpose_feedback, 'Suggestions' %> 
    <%= radio_button_tag :purpose, '2' %><%= label_tag :purpose_prayer, 'Prayer Request' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :purpose, '3' %><%= label_tag :purpose_praise, 'Testimony' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :purpose, '4' %><%= label_tag :purpose_bug, 'Defects/Bugs' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag :purpose, '5' %><%= label_tag :purpose_other, 'Other' %>
```

I have the radio button with six text fields on my form.  I do error checking field by field in my controller, starting with the radio button which is at the top of the form.  The error checking is checking all my fields correctly.  However if I select one of the radio button values for params[:purpose] the value is populated properly but the radio button is not checked when the view is displayed.  If I select purpose and enter values for three text fields for example, the values of the text fields are still on the form but the radio button is unchecked even though purpose has a value.

I found this link [How to set the value of radio button after submitting form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161135/how-to-set-the-value-of-radio-button-after-submitting-form) and developed the following code in my controller:

```
  def check_radio_button

    case params[:purpose]
    when '1'
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, '1', :checked => true)
    when '2'
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, '2', :checked => true)
    when '3'
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, '3', :checked => true)
    when '4'
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, '4', :checked => true)
    when '5'
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, '5', :checked => true)
    end

  end
```

When I tried to display my view selecting the first radio button (purpose = '1') I got the following error:

```
undefined method `radio_button_tag' for #<PagesController:0x007f94d05c5e88>
```

The line where it got the error was the one where params[:purpose] == 1 showing that purpose is populated properly.

Other examples about checking the radio button were used with form_for where databases were updated.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will keep looking.

UPDATE: 4/4/3012 11:15 am CST

My radio button is being checked now.  I moved the corrected logic to the helper as suggested by Mischa.

Here is my helper code:

```
  def check_radio_button (purpose)

    if params[:purpose].blank?
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, purpose)
    elsif purpose == params[:purpose]
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, purpose, :checked => true)
    else
      radio_button_tag(:purpose, purpose)
    end

  end
```

Here is my view code that I rewrote as suggested by Catfish:

```
    <%= check_radio_button("1") %><%= label_tag :purpose_feedback, 'Suggestions' %> 
    <%= check_radio_button("2") %><%= label_tag :purpose_prayer, 'Prayer Request' %>
    <%= check_radio_button("3") %><%= label_tag :purpose_praise, 'Testimony' %>
    <%= check_radio_button("4") %><%= label_tag :purpose_bug, 'Defects/Bugs' %>
    <%= check_radio_button("5") %><%= label_tag :purpose_other, 'Other' %>
```

Comment: `check_radio_button` shouldn't be in your controller, but in a helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `radio_button_tag` is not a function to be used in your controller. The link that you posted has radio_button_tag in a helper.

Re-read the question that you posted and try it again.

Basically you create a helper method that renders a check_box_tag and then you call that helper method in your view:

Example helper

```
def my_check_box_tag(my_param) do
  ....
end
```

In my view

```
<%= my_check_box_tag("test") %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I updated my question with my solution.  This was the last issue I had before being able to deploy my application.  Works like a charm.